# GPIO won't work with Pure Data extended

Tags: gpio, boot-issues, script, pi-b+, puredata

I'm running a script at log-in on my Raspberry Pi B+ (I call it in the `.bashrc`).
The script runs Jack-Audio and then launch a Pure Data patch that deals with audio and GPIOs. The audio part works well but not the GPIO one (a led should be on when the Pd patch opens and a button should let me switch it on/off).

It looks like `pdwiringPi` can't speak to GPIOs when called in a script on log-in whereas when I run this script manually after logging in, it works fine.

I precise that I don't have any errors whatever the method I use (automatic on log-in or manually after logging in)

Am I doing something wrong when using the `pdwiringPi` in Pure Data at log-in?

Here is the script:

```
export DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:path=/run/dbus/system_bus_socket  
sleep 2  
jackd -dalsa -D -i 2 -o 2 -n 3 -r 44100 -p 256 -P&  
sleep 2  
pd-extended -rt -jack -nogui  -open wire.pd
```

Comment: Welcome -- please take [the tour](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour).  If you are trying to find out why your script does not work in a specific context, **we need to see some code.**

Comment: Hi, I've just reworded my problem and added the script. Hope it helps.

Comment: Wow, I missed this in the reopen queue.  That is 100% my fault -- I'm very sorry.  You'd be better off reposting this question now as it is too old to get noticed if reopened (and I can't effect that).  I'd also suggest you try [the first method here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20564208/1151724) to redirect output to a log file so you can see any errors, etc. that may occur when run at boot.  You will have to define `$LOG_FILE`, e.g. `LOG_FILE=/tmp/mybootscript.log`.